# Check for sub field existence in Mongodb java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using mongodb version 3.4, with java driver.

I have a collection of jsons of this format:

```
{
    "foo": {
    "d4231ds": {
        "type":"A",
        "color":"red"
    },
    "dmncxa3s": {
        "type":"B",
        "color":"yellow"
    },

    "JsdjS8": {
        "type":"A",
        "color":"red"
    },

    "SKJDcxar3": {
        "type":"C",
        "color":"green"
    }
    },
    "bar": "100011"
}
```

I need to get all the documents which have "type":"A", using java. The keys under foo (d4231ds,dmncxa3s etc) aren't known in advance, and differ between the documents. Hence, using the dot operator is not working in this case.

I've tried looking on several methods, but non seemed to achieve this.

Comment: Show what You tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation in latest 3.4 server version.

Use `$objectToArray` to convert the named keys into key value pair ( `k, v` ) and use `$in` to query the value document for field `type = A`.

`$redact` which acts on the results from query filter, `$$KEEP` when match else `$$PRUNE`

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
 MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(db_name);
 MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = database.getCollection(collection_name);
 Document query = Document.parse("{\"$redact\":{\"$cond\":[{\"$let\":{\"vars\":{\"subelems\":{\"$objectToArray\":\"$foo\"}},\"in\":{\"$in\":[\"A\",\"$$subelems.v.type\"]}}},\"$$KEEP\",\"$$PRUNE\"]}}");
 List<Document> result = mongoCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(query)).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Mongo Shell Query:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {
    "$redact": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$let": {
            "vars": {
              "subelems": {
                "$objectToArray": "$foo"
              }
            },
            "in": {
              "$in": [
                "A",
                "$$subelems.v.type"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```